# Load resource referencing ressources in Java Webapp

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, xslt, resources

I got a xslt transformation done with something like this:

```
public static String transform(Source xml, String xsltPath) {

    try {
        InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(xsltPath);
        final Source xslt = new StreamSource(is);
        final TransformerFactory transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xslt);
        final OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        final StreamResult result = new StreamResult(os);
        trans.transform(xml, new StreamResult(os));
        final String theResult = result.getOutputStream().toString();
        return theResult;
    }
    catch (TransformerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see xslt is loaded from resources. The function together with the transformation files i need are bundled in a library and this works as long as the library is stand alone from a main method or so. 
However if this library is bundled with a webapplication and deployed in Jetty/Tomcat it gets a bit complicated. As long as the transformation files in it self do not reference any other files from resources there is no problem but with files like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet>

  <xsl:import href="import_file1.xsl" />
  <xsl:import href="import_file2.xsl" />

  <xsl:template name="aTtemplate">
    <xsl:for-each select="document('import_file3.xml')">
    ...
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The imports cannot be resolved and the document from the for each loop cannot be found. In Tomcat a workaround is to put the files inside the $TOMCAT/bin directory but that is not a suitable solution for us. Is there any method to get this resources recursively out of the lib?

Comment: You could try loading your files via Java and passing their absolute paths to XSLT through global parameters.

Comment: You should define a uri resolver for your application and load the documents through it, using a custom protocol.  Something like 'context:/template.xsl'.  Then the relative imports will be able to resolve.

Comment: URIResolver is the keyword I needed thanks its simpler than i thought here :)